# Ace: Disabling view changes on pressing key, still want info on change occured

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

i'm new to Ace Editor API. 
Issue: I want to disable "immediate" updates in the view when a key is pressed., I want to transform these changes according to my need say 'buffer' these changes and make these text-changes later using insert method mentioned in the documentation. 
Documentation mentions a setReadOnly method to disable changes in the document but it also disables the text-change notifications. 
How can I achieve the desired the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change event can be used only as a notification, it is fired after the document is actually changed.
If you want to buffer user input you can add a keyboardHandler that prevents the change event

```
editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler(function(data, hashId, keyString, keyCode, e) {
   if (hashId == -1) {
       console.log("typed text", keyString)
       return {command: "null"}; // do nothing
   }

})
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful, but now i've to make my own keybindings for every event, can i somehow use the default bindings along with this

Comment: for events that you do not want to handle do not return the {command} object